# MySQL multiple variables in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join

I have table `dates` as following

```
"dates"  "one" "two"  "three" "four"
date1    id1    id2    id3    id4
date2    id3    id1    id4    id2
```

and a second table  `id2name`

```
"ids"  "names"
id1    name1
id2    name2
id3    name3
id4    name4
```

I have a mental block trying to write

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE `date`='$date' LEFT JOIN `id2name` ON ...
```

What clause do I put in ON to get names instead of IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model looks denormalized, but this should get you started:

```
SELECT
  d.`date`,
  i1.names AS name1,
  i2.names AS name2,
  ...
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN `id2name` i1 ON ( i1.ids = d.one )
LEFT JOIN `id2name` i2 ON ( i2.ids = d.two )
...
WHERE `date`='$date'
```

Comment: Also, what structure would you propose? Appreciate answers!

Comment: @selytch: The proposed model would depend on your requirements. If there are always exactly 4 `ids` per `date`, and you need to select them like this, your model will work fine. If more ids are going to come (`five`, `six`), then you have to change your model for every new `id`. Feel free to submit another question explaining your model and what you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can only join on one id at a time so you'll have to do a join on each column that has these id's